# Wordpress Custom Menu w/JavaScript

Tags: php, wordpress

I want a custom menu in my WordPress site.

I want a menu for each category that, when clicked, expands to show the articles within.

```
[+Menu 1]
[-Menu 2]
  post a
  post b
  ...
[+Menu 3]
```

- Each Menu Header represents a WordPress Category.
- Submenu Items are Posts.
- When a Menu Header is clicked, its menu opens to show post links without any page refresh.

I need WordPress to output the page links as list items for each menu item, for each category.

The JavaScript part, I can do.

How do I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Does [THIS ANSWER](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26446/add-posts-from-a-category-to-menu-with-all-posts-in-it-as-sub-menu) help you out?

Comment: Oh, I found sidebar.php under Theme File Editor! Where's the function wp_nav_menu? That looks like what's doing the outputting of the menu items. It's not in functions.php. Where can I find it?

Comment: ```
<?php
     // Primary navigation menu.
     wp_nav_menu(
      array(
       'menu_class'     => 'nav-menu',
       'theme_location' => 'primary',
      )
     );
    ?>
```
?